# Select a record with highest amount by joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've 2 tables Sales & Purchase, Sales table with fields SaleId, Rate, Quantity, Date, CompanyId, UserID. Purchase table with fields PurchaseId, Rate, Quantity, Date, CompanyId, UserID.

I want to select a record from either table that have highest Rate*Quantity.

```
SELECT SalesId Or PurchaseId FROM Sales,Purchase 
where Sales.UserId=Purchase.UserId and Sales.CompanyId=Purchase.CompanyId 
AND Sales.Date=Current date 
AND Purchase.Date=Current date AND Sales.UserId=1 
AND Purchase.UserId=1 AND Sales.CompanyId=1 AND Purchase.ComoanyId=1
```

Comment: Ouch, please format your question so it's readable :-)

Comment: kindly have a look, i've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select top 1 * from
(select SalesId ID, Rate, Quantity, 'Sales' TransactionType
 from sales
 union all
 select PurchaseId ID, Rate, Quantity, 'Purchase' TransactionType
 from purchase)
order by Rate * Quantity desc
```

Comment: I want to know Id whether it belongs to Sales table or Purchase table,

Comment: dude you rock! you deserve 27.2K seriously :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ... ORDER BY Rate * Quantity DESC
```

or

```
SELECT ... WHERE Rate * Quantity = (SELECT max(Rate * Quantity) FROM ... )
```

You might also consider if there are two equal 'max' records. (The second option would return both, the first just one - at random)

Comment: ORDER BY .. **DESC**, because implicitly ordering is done in an ASCENDING manner.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use `MAX` and `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT MAX(RateQty) FROM
( SELECT Rate*Quantity as RateQty
  FROM Sales
  WHERE Sales.UserId=1 AND Sales.CompanyId=1 AND Sales.Date = GETDATE()
  UNION ALL
  SELEC Rate*Quantity as RateQty
  FROM Purchase
  WHERE Purchase.UserId=1 AND Purchase.CompanyId=1 AND  Purchase.Date= GETDATE()
) SalesPurchase
```